# Kernel recognition of changed USB state, but lacking correct higher level USB status feedback

Tags: linux, usb

```
$ dmesg | grep usb
```

... shows status change in USB on plug / unplug

```
$ lsusb -v
```

lists the USB as a 'hub'

```
$ usb-devices
```

doesn't give me the desired output of:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  6 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=06c2 ProdID=007b Rev=01.01
S:  Manufacturer=Phidgets Inc.
S:  Product=PhidgetStepper
S:  SerialNumber=267330
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=96mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
```

... but instead:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 3
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.05
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.5.0-mt9v034+ ehci_hcd
S:  Product=OMAP-EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=ehci-omap.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

Any ideas on what might be the cause of the low-level kernel picking up the changes in USB ... but no higher level identification of the device (such as that with `usb-devices`)?

It's also worth noting that this is attempting to control a phidgets stepper, with a verified correct installation on Linux per [these directions](http://www.phidgets.com/docs/OS_-_Linux#Software).

On bootup of host I also happen to get this error via `dmesg`:

```
[    0.152526] usbhs_omap usbhs_omap: xclk60mhsp2_ck set parentfailed error:-22
```

And this new command I just found:

```
$ hwinfo --usb
```

Happens to give a error-filled output:

```
hal.1: read hal dataprocess 1711: arguments to dbus_move_error() were incorrect, assertion "(dest) == NULL || !dbus_error_is_set ((dest))" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-errors.c line 282.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
libhal.c 3483 : Error unsubscribing to signals, error=The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
07: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub                                         
[Created at usb.122]
Unique ID: k4bc.qEeA4IsuqFC
SysFS ID: /devices/platform/usbhs_omap/ehci-omap.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-0:1.0
Hardware Class: hub
Model: "Linux 3.5.0-mt9v034+ ehci_hcd OMAP-EHCI Host Controller"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux 3.5.0-mt9v034+ ehci_hcd"
Device: usb 0x0002 "OMAP-EHCI Host Controller"
Revision: "3.05"
Serial ID: "ehci-omap.0"
Driver: "hub"
Driver Modules: "usbcore"
Speed: 480 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0002d0305dc09dsc00dp00ic09isc00ip00"
Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

Edit:

After installing hal

```
$ sudo apt-get install hal
```

The output from

```
$ hwinfo --usb
```

cleaned up:

```
07: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub                                         
[Created at usb.122]
UDI: /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_1d6b_2_ehci_omap_0_if0
Unique ID: k4bc.qEeA4IsuqFC
SysFS ID: /devices/platform/usbhs_omap/ehci-omap.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
SysFS BusID: 1-0:1.0
Hardware Class: hub
Model: "Linux 3.5.0-mt9v034+ ehci_hcd OMAP-EHCI Host Controller"
Hotplug: USB
Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux 3.5.0-mt9v034+ ehci_hcd"
Device: usb 0x0002 "OMAP-EHCI Host Controller"
Revision: "3.05"
Serial ID: "ehci-omap.0"
Driver: "hub"
Driver Modules: "usbcore"
Speed: 480 Mbps
Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0002d0305dc09dsc00dp00ic09isc00ip00"
Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

Bootup also seems to be throwing an issue:

$ dmesg grep | usb

showing these two errors on startup:

```
[    0.067077]  usbhs_omap: alias fck already exists
...
[    0.152496] usbhs_omap usbhs_omap: xclk60mhsp2_ck set parentfailed error:-22
```

PER REQUEST:

```
$ sudo uname -a
Linux statler 3.5.0-mt9v034+ #1 PREEMPT Thu May 30 22:23:53 UTC 2013 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

... and the output from:
    $ sudo lsusb -v

https://gist.github.com/delinquentme/890532515002c503815e

Answer (score 2):

Is your USB configured in the BIOS and Linux for legacy mode and/or USB 3.0? It looks like it may be trying to use either or while both aren't setup for it.

Looking up the vendor ID given in the hwinfo --usb output suggests it's an issue with your video and/or USB driver not being properly configured. Since you need EHCI for USB to work properly, and that shows your HAL is throwing errors, it's safe to say that is where your USB issues are coming from.

Update: It appears certain versions of that board may not support USB 2.0 or may need to be have USB_OTG support built in. I've found a couple guides for the beagle board that should cover any setup you may have, but there are too many possibilities to cover them all here.

P.S. If you are using something other then a beagleboard these will still provide good info for that chip, but of course you won't want to flash anything from it directly to your device.

For an overview of the differences between some of them USB types and what they can do see:
http://elinux.org/BeagleBoard#EHCI

uboot patches for boards with different USB configurations:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/2xhpUT2jzLE/discussion

Core Linux USB drivers for OMAP:
http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MFD_OMAP_USB_HOST.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're thinking this is the issue based off the error? What part?

Comment: If you have questions about the question please consider leaving an comment

Comment: usb-devices is showing your EHCI controller (USB 2.0) instead of the device (Ver 1.1). Since the EHCI hub only uses 2.0 it should be letting another controller work with the device. The info from hwinfo -usb looks like it may be referring to your graphics driver? (mt9v034) TBH I'm not really sure what to think of that one.

Comment: @50-3 Unfortunately I can't add comments, not enough rep here yet.

Comment: so I've $ sudo apt-get install hal  ... and the output from $ hwinfo --usb has cleaned up and now shows no error, but I'm still not getting the desired output from $lsusb

Comment: $ usb-devices rather ... which would return the info about the "Phidgets" device

Comment: you may need to do a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure it doesn't miss anything. There were a few other similar errors I found on google but none specific to the usb like yours. The `usbcore` module also seems to be the unique feature here.

Comment: After the apt-get upgrade can you please add the output for `uname -a` and `sudo lsusb -v`?

Comment: The answer has been update with what all I was able to find. It looks like there are a lot of possibilities but they all depend on the physical configuration of the board.